# use responsive file manager with tinymce - create a user session

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, file-manager

I have just installed tinymce and I chose responivefilemanager to handle the file browsing part.
I finally succeeded to make it work!

now I'm trying to prevent users from sharing files.

Can someone help me configure the $_SESSION["subfolder"] parameter or anything else allowing the users to not share folders with other users ?

Also, is it possible to start responsive file manager with the upload display?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand theproblem, in your file.php where you use tinyMCE:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["RF"]["subfolder"] = "folder_user1" //subfolder of your user
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    ...
    <textarea id="mytextarea" name="txtarea"></textarea>
    ...

</body>
</html>
```

And in your site directory:

```
root
-uploads //your directory where files are uploaded
--folder_user1
--folder_user2
--...
```